# React Anonymous Component Function ESLint Errors

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I need help resolving these lint errors on this React anonymous function.

```
export default {
  "text": () => { return <div className="item-icon">txt</div>; },
  "image": (props) => { return <img className="preview-img" src={props.src} alt=''/>; }
};
```

Here are the lint errors

```
  4:11  error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
  5:12  error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
  5:72  error  'src' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this resolved them.

```
const text = () => { return <div className="item-icon">txt</div>; };
text.displayName = 'text';

const image = (props) => { return <img className="preview-img" src={props.src} alt=''/>; }
image.displayName = "image";
image.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.string
};

export default { text, image }
```